# How do I set the width of the bars in an Oxyplot column plot?

Tags: wpf, xaml, oxyplot

I'm trying to set the width of the bars in my column series, but setting `ColumnWidth` on the `ColumnSeries` is having no effect. How can I influence the width of the columns?

```
<oxy:Plot>
    <oxy:Plot.Series>
        <oxy:ColumnSeries ColumnWidth="1000" />
    </oxy:Plot.Series>
    <oxy:Plot.Axes>
        <oxy:CategoryAxis Key="CategoryAxis" />
        <oxy:LinearAxis  />
    </oxy:Plot.Axes>
</oxy:Plot>
```

Comment: See also [this explanation by VisualMelon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70002317/199364).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [OxyPlot source](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Series/BarSeries/ColumnSeries.cs#L86), we can see that the actual bar width is calculated as follows. You should be able to achieve your desired effect by tweaking `GapWidth` and `MaxWidth`.

```
protected override double GetActualBarWidth()
{
    var categoryAxis = this.GetCategoryAxis();
    return this.ColumnWidth / (1 + categoryAxis.GapWidth) / categoryAxis.MaxWidth;
}
```

Comment: And if for some reason you needed even more control, it looks like you could make a subclass: `public class MyColumnSeries : ColumnSeries { ... protected override double GetActualBarWidth() { ...any-code-you-want... } ... }`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I just tried to make a subclass of ColumnSeries, but nothing changed. Can you see my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998490/oxyplot-bar-width

Comment: @user979331 - of course you have to **use** your subclass. Where you currently do `new ColumnSeries`, you instead do `new MyColumnSeries`. Otherwise, the existing ColumnSeries code continues to be executed. This is a fundamental OO principle.