# OxyPlot: Change LinearBarSeries bar wdth

Tags: c#, width, oxyplot

How can I change width of the bars in a `LinearBarSeries`. I tried changing the `BarWidth` property but no effect.

```
var series = new LinearBarSeries() {
    BarWidth = 5
};
foreach (var value in values) {
    series.Points.Add(new DataPoint(DateTimeAxis.ToDouble(value.DateTime), value.Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See a similar answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50453471/246758

You might need to tweak the property 'GapWidth'.  From Oxyplot's source code for BarSeries:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the actual width/height of the items of this series.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The width or height.</returns>
    /// <remarks>The actual width is also influenced by the GapWidth of the CategoryAxis used by this series.</remarks>
    protected override double GetActualBarWidth()
    {
        var categoryAxis = this.GetCategoryAxis();
        return this.BarWidth / (1 + categoryAxis.GapWidth) / categoryAxis.GetMaxWidth();
    }
```