# Oxyplot Bar Width

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I am using Oxyplot to make bar chart. Is there anyway to change the width of the bar?

I found this solution:

```
protected override double GetActualBarWidth()
{
    var categoryAxis = this.GetCategoryAxis();
    return this.ColumnWidth / (1 + categoryAxis.GapWidth) / categoryAxis.MaxWidth;
}
```

From here:

[How do I set the width of the bars in an Oxyplot column plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453469/how-do-i-set-the-width-of-the-bars-in-an-oxyplot-column-plot)

But I don't understand how to apply it.

Here is my code:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel></local:MainPageViewModel>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
<oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model}" HeightRequest="200" />
```

And here is my view model:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public PlotModel Model { get; set; }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            CategoryAxis xaxis = new CategoryAxis();
            xaxis.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
            xaxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorTickSize = 0;
            xaxis.MajorTickSize = 0;
            xaxis.TextColor = OxyColors.Gray;
            xaxis.FontSize = 10.0;
            xaxis.Labels.Add("S");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("M");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("T");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("W");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("T");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("F");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("S");

            LinearAxis yaxis = new LinearAxis();
            yaxis.Position = AxisPosition.Left;
            yaxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            yaxis.MinorTickSize = 0;
            yaxis.MajorTickSize = 0;
            yaxis.TextColor = OxyColors.Gray;
            yaxis.FontSize = 10.0;
            yaxis.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

            ColumnSeries s2 = new ColumnSeries();
            s2.LabelPlacement = LabelPlacement.Inside;
            s2.LabelFormatString = "{0}";
            s2.TextColor = OxyColors.White;
            s2.ColumnWidth = 5.0;
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(50),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(40),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(30),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(20),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(30),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
           
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(40),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(50),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            

            Model = new PlotModel();
            Model.Axes.Add(xaxis);
            Model.Axes.Add(yaxis);
            Model.Series.Add(s2);
            Model.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.Transparent;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I believe you would have to subclass whatever has `GetActualBarWidth()`, then use that snippet you have at the top to override that method. Probably a series class or something like that, based on a very cursory google search.

Comment: Looks like you would subclass `ColumnSeries`.

Comment: @Steve, so outside of my MainPageViewModel class, create another class like so public class BarChartClass : ColumnSeries {

Comment: @Steve or can I extend the class MainPageViewModel

Comment: @Steve, I tried extending MainPageViewModel : ColumnSeries, I get no errors, but the class is not getting called

Comment: It makes no sense to do `MainPageViewModel : ColumnSeries`. Instead, create `MyColumnSeries : ColumnSeries`, and add `override double GetActualBarWidth` there. THEN instead of `new ColumnSeries`, do `new MyColumnSeries`, so that your override gets used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set the width of the bars in an Oxyplot column plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50453469/how-do-i-set-the-width-of-the-bars-in-an-oxyplot-column-plot)

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I tried that and it did not work, setting the gap width worked

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve side question, am I able to have a oxyplot in a CollectionView?

Comment: I don't know. You'll just have to try it.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I did try it and it did not appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve it by changing GapWidth. The larger the value, the smaller the width.

```
  xaxis.GapWidth = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the given answer,

`ColumnWidth` is (perhaps confusingly) used to determine the relative size of bars which share an axis.

The width that all bars (in your case, just the one) consume on an axis is determined - as noted by others - by the `CategoryAxis.GapWidth` property independent of the relative widths of the series. The property is the ratio of empty space (the gap) to the non-empty space (so the default of `1` is a 1:1 empty/not-empty ratio; a value less than 1 will commit more space to the bars).

The answer you link merely showing you how the width is computed internally: the confusion is that the `MaxWidth` depends on the reported widths of the series, so the ratio is pretty useless when you have a single series.