# Xamarin.Forms - oxyplot not displaying inside CollectionView

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I am using Oxyplot and honestly its the best chart builder out there for xamarin forms. I was able to build my chart outside of the collection view just to see what it would look like. Now I want to add in a collection view but it is not appearing, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my collectionview

```
<CollectionView x:Name="Kids">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding chart}" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="100" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Here is what I am assigning to my collectionview

```
List<ReportsClass> newKidList = new List<ReportsClass>();

ReportsClass item = new ReportsClass();

item.chart = new MainPageViewModel();

newsKidList.Add(item);

Kids.ItemsSource = newKidList;
```

Here is my ReportsClass

```
public class ReportsClass
    {
        public MainPageViewModel chart { get; set; }
        
    }
```

And here is my view model

```
public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public PlotModel Model { get; set; }

        

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            CategoryAxis xaxis = new CategoryAxis();
            xaxis.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
            xaxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorTickSize = 0;
            xaxis.MajorTickSize = 0;
            xaxis.TextColor = OxyColors.Gray;
            xaxis.FontSize = 10.0;
            xaxis.Labels.Add("S");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("M");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("T");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("W");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("T");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("F");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("S");
            xaxis.GapWidth = 10.0;
            

            LinearAxis yaxis = new LinearAxis();
            yaxis.Position = AxisPosition.Left;
            yaxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            yaxis.MinorTickSize = 0;
            yaxis.MajorTickSize = 0;
            yaxis.TextColor = OxyColors.Gray;
            yaxis.FontSize = 10.0;
            yaxis.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            

            ColumnSeries s2 = new ColumnSeries();
            s2.TextColor = OxyColors.White;

            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(50),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(40),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(30),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(20),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(30),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")

            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(40),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Convert.ToDouble(50),
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });


            Model = new PlotModel();
            Model.Axes.Add(xaxis);
            Model.Axes.Add(yaxis);
            Model.Series.Add(s2);
            Model.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.Transparent;
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE**

My Reports Class changed

```
public class ReportsClass
        {
            public PlotModel chart { get; set; }
            
        }
```

This code in my xaml.cs

```
List<ReportsClass> newKidList = new List<ReportsClass>();
    
    ReportsClass item = new ReportsClass();
    
    MainPageViewModel mv = new MainPageViewModel();

    item.chart = mv.Model;
    
    newsKidList.Add(item);
    
    Kids.ItemsSource = newKidList;
```

Still nothing is showing

**UPDATE**

I didn't really think of it at the time, but my oxyplot is inside an expander:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="Kids">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <xct:Expander>
                        <xct:Expander.Header>
                            <Frame Padding="0" CornerRadius="10" Margin="5" BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="False">
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Grid BackgroundColor="#f8f8f8">
                                        <StackLayout Padding="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image x:Name="kidProfile" Source="{Binding image}" WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="75" HorizontalOptions="Start" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                                <Label Text="{Binding first_name}"></Label>
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <Label Text="Grade: " FontSize="Small"></Label>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding grade}" FontSize="Small"></Label>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            
                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <Image Margin="20" HorizontalOptions="End" Source="arrowDown.png" HeightRequest="15">
                                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        </Image>
                                    </Grid>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </xct:Expander.Header>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackLayout x:Name="KidData">
                                    
                                    <Grid WidthRequest="150" HeightRequest="150" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" Padding="0,10,0,20">
                                        <oxy:PlotView HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200" Model="{Binding chart}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
                                    </Grid>
                                    
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                    </xct:Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

When I put my oxyplot out the extender but still inside the collectionview it does appear.

**UPDATE**

I am open to an alternative to the collectionview seeing as the collectionview sometimes has unwanted behavour.

I did get my oxplot to appear but using Expander Tapped attribute `Tapped="Expander_Tapped"` and I would call the data again, but it would close the expander because it would be grabbing the data for the collection view again.

Comment: `Model="{Binding chart.Model}"`

Comment: Trying this now @Jason

Comment: @Jason, it still did not work, as the bar chart is still not showing

Comment: did you use the same model classes for your other test?  Did you use the same sized container for the chart?

Comment: @Jason is an old question that has my old code with the working example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998490/oxyplot-bar-width

Comment: in that example you are binding to `Model`, which is the same thing I suggested

Comment: Yea, everything looks good, just appearing

Comment: If you made the change Jason suggested, please edit your question to show the **exact code** you are using now. (If you did not make any change, then do it now. Do exactly what he typed.)

Comment: I updated my question, its weird it not showing up in a collection view

Comment: Updated my question, its an extender that is breaking it

Comment: It is a bad practice to use Expander in `CollectionView` , it may cause the  unwanted behavior , refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/expander .

Comment: Can you make a public github repo that demonstrates the use of oxyplot, and the bug?

Comment: Also, what is the maximum number of items you have in the collection? Can you limit it to a fixed maximum such as 10 items? If so, there are ways to implement this that don't require one of the collection classes. To avoid certain bugs.

Comment: Yea I'll make a github, I cant see it being more than 5 or 6

Comment: For future readers: This is solved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368607/c-sharp-xamarin-forms-oxyplot-chart-this-plotmodel-is-already-in-use-by-so. See that Q&A for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers: The issues in question are solved by [Error This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control in OxyPlot chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70368607/error-this-plotmodel-is-already-in-use-by-some-other-plotview-control-in-oxyplot) Q&A.

---

- "I did get my oxyplot to appear by using Expander Tapped attribute ..."

In view:

```
<xct:Expander Tapped="Expander_Tapped" ...
```

In code-behind:

```
void Expander_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

---

- "but it would close the expander because it would be grabbing the data for the collection view again."

Add lines to Expander_Tapped:

```
void Expander_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // --- ADD THESE LINES ---
    if (ReferenceEquals(sender, expander)) {
        // User is tapping the existing expander. Don't do anything special.
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

---

Other details involving use of OnPropertyChanged can be seen in the code of that other question.

Or in [github ToolmakerSteve, repo OxyplotApp1](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/OxyplotApp1).