# Error This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control in OxyPlot chart

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I am using Xamarin.Forms OxyPlot Chart. I have a collectionview and in each collectionview item has an expander and inside each of those expanders is a PlotView

```
<CollectionView x:Name="Kids">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <xct:Expander Tapped="Expander_Tapped" ClassId="{Binding rowNumber}">
            <xct:Expander.Header>
                <Frame Padding="0" CornerRadius="10" Margin="5" BackgroundColor="White" HasShadow="False">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="#f8f8f8">
                            <StackLayout Padding="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image x:Name="kidProfile" Source="{Binding image}" WidthRequest="75" HeightRequest="75" HorizontalOptions="Start" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding first_name}"></Label>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Text="Grade: " FontSize="Small"></Label>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding grade}" FontSize="Small"></Label>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Image Margin="20" HorizontalOptions="End" Source="arrowDown.png" HeightRequest="15"></Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
             </xct:Expander.Header>
             <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding chart}" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="100" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

and I was assigning the PlotModel in my class

```
public class ReportsClass
{
    public PlotModel chart
    {
        get
        {
            PlotModel model = new PlotModel();

            CategoryAxis xaxis = new CategoryAxis();
            xaxis.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
            xaxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorTickSize = 0;
            xaxis.MajorTickSize = 0;
            xaxis.TextColor = OxyColors.Gray;
            xaxis.FontSize = 10.0;
            xaxis.Labels.Add("S");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("M");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("T");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("W");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("T");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("F");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("S");
            xaxis.GapWidth = 10.0;
            xaxis.IsPanEnabled = false;
            xaxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;


            LinearAxis yaxis = new LinearAxis();
            yaxis.Position = AxisPosition.Left;
            yaxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            yaxis.MinorTickSize = 0;
            yaxis.MajorTickSize = 0;
            yaxis.TextColor = OxyColors.Gray;
            yaxis.FontSize = 10.0;
            yaxis.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            yaxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;
            yaxis.IsPanEnabled = false;


            ColumnSeries s2 = new ColumnSeries();
            s2.TextColor = OxyColors.White;

            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Sunday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Monday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Tuesday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Wednesday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Thursday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")

            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Friday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = Saturday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });

            model.Axes.Add(xaxis);
            model.Axes.Add(yaxis);
            model.Series.Add(s2);
            model.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.Transparent;

            return model;
        }
    }
    
}
```

Now this works, but in the Expander when I expand an item the PlotView would not show, at all. So I changed my Class to use INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class ReportsClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public PlotModel chart
    {
        get => _chart;
        set
        {
            _chart = value;
            if(_chart.PlotView == null && value.PlotView == null)
            {
                OnPropertyChanged("chart");
            }

        }
    }
    public PlotModel _chart;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            if(this.chart.PlotView == null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
    }
}
```

And in my code behind I use the expander's tapped method to populate the PlotView:

```
void Expander_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(expander != null)
    {
        expander.IsExpanded = false;
    }
    
    expander = sender as Expander;

    int id = Convert.ToInt32(expander.ClassId);

    ReportsClass item = newKidList[id];

    Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
    {
        if (item.chart == null)
        {
            PlotModel model = new PlotModel();

            CategoryAxis xaxis = new CategoryAxis();
            xaxis.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
            xaxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorTickSize = 0;
            xaxis.MajorTickSize = 0;
            xaxis.TextColor = OxyColors.Gray;
            xaxis.FontSize = 10.0;
            xaxis.Labels.Add("S");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("M");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("T");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("W");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("T");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("F");
            xaxis.Labels.Add("S");
            xaxis.GapWidth = 10.0;
            xaxis.IsPanEnabled = false;
            xaxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;


            LinearAxis yaxis = new LinearAxis();
            yaxis.Position = AxisPosition.Left;
            yaxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            xaxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
            yaxis.MinorTickSize = 0;
            yaxis.MajorTickSize = 0;
            yaxis.TextColor = OxyColors.Gray;
            yaxis.FontSize = 10.0;
            yaxis.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
            yaxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;
            yaxis.IsPanEnabled = false;


            ColumnSeries s2 = new ColumnSeries();
            s2.TextColor = OxyColors.White;

            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = item.Sunday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = item.Monday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = item.Tuesday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = item.Wednesday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = item.Thursday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")

            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = item.Friday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });
            s2.Items.Add(new ColumnItem
            {
                Value = item.Saturday,
                Color = OxyColor.Parse("#02cc9d")
            });

            model.Axes.Add(xaxis);
            model.Axes.Add(yaxis);
            model.Series.Add(s2);
            model.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.Transparent;

            item.chart = model;
        }

        return false;
    });
}
```

However, eventually I will get this error:

This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control

Now I understand that there is a one-to-one relation between the PlotView and its PlotModel, which gives us the error, so I have tried to do a check to see if PlotModel has a PlotView, but I am still getting this error.

I found this solution:

> If you set the parent View of your OxyPlot to a DataTemplate that
> creates a new OxyPlot each time then the OxyPlot cannot be cached. A
> new PlotModel and PlotView is created each time and this error is
> avoided (at least that seems to work for me, I am using CarouselView)

https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-xamarin/issues/17

But I do not know how to do this for a collection view, any help would be much apperciated.

I also found this:

> This is a very common issue of OxyPlot when it's used in MVVM. In
> OxyPlot, the view and the model are 1-to-1 mapped, when a second view
> is trying to bind the same PlotModel, you have the issue of "PlotModel
> is already in use by some other PlotView control". On iOS, ListView's
> cell will be re-created when it is scrolling. In this case, there will
> be a newly created view trying to bind the same PlotModel, and then
> you have the issue. On Android, I guess you will have the same issue
> too. Try to put your phone from landscape to portrait, see if you have
> the same issue. In Android, the view will be re-created completely
> when the orientation is changed.
>
> A quick fix is to break the MVVM design here a little bit. Don't
> create the model in a separated place but create the model in the
> view. So whenever a view is re-created by iOS or Android, a new model
> is also re-created.

https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-xamarin/issues/60

But I don't know how to apply this part:

> A quick fix is to break the MVVM design here a little bit. Don't
> create the model in a separated place but create the model in the
> view. So whenever a view is re-created by iOS or Android, a new model
> is also re-created.

Comment: Do you need to have more than one expander open at a time? If not, it would be easier to not use expander, use a popup. Then it won't get instantiated until opened. I realize that isn't as nice a user experience, but its a fallback solution.

Comment: No, I only have one expander open at a time. I close the previous open expander on tapped....Hi again Steve!

Comment: Hi - still waiting for that oxyplot repo :)  ok, there must be something you need to clear when closing the previous one.

Comment: I believe I first followed this link to setup: https://parallelcodes.com/xamarin-forms-creating-bar-graph-charts-with-oxyplot/

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve just an FYI in I am testing with 4 items in my collectionview

Comment: What source file is method `void Expander_Tapped` in? It refers to "expander", which doesn't exist in the code you've shown. And its inside `ItemTemplate`, so it needs to refer to the specific Expander that is part of the current item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240185/discussion-between-toolmakersteve-and-user979331).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [github ToolmakerSteve / repo OxyplotApp1](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/OxyplotApp1), for working version.

---

*"This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control"*

After various tests on iOS, I conclude that using (CollectionView or ListView) + Expander + Oxyplot on iOS is fundamentally not reliable.

Oxyplot seems to worsen known issues with [Expander and CollectionView](https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinCommunityToolkit/issues/1283).

Therefore, the most important fix is to stop using these collection views. Replace use of `CollectionView` with:

```
<StackLayout Spacing="0" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding KidModels}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
```

---

For better performance, make this change, so each graph is only created the first time a user clicks a given item:

```
void Expander_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // --- ADD THESE LINES ---
    if (ReferenceEquals(sender, expander)) {
        // User is tapping the existing expander. Don't do anything special.
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

NOTE: Also fixes a problem where expander immediately closed again, if user tapped it three times in a row.

---

Faster appearance the first time each expander is clicked. Here are three alternatives. From fastest to slowest. Use the first, but if ever get a blank graph or other problem, switch to second. If second still has problems, switch to third - which is the original, though with a slightly shorter time delay:

```
if (item.Chart == null) {
    PlotModel model = CreateReportChart(item);
    Action action = () => {
        item.Chart = model;
    };
    if (false) {
        action();
    } else if (true) {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
            action();
        });
    } else {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5), () => {
            action();

            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

---

OPTIONAL: To be sure expander animation doesn't cause a problem when used with Oxyplot.

If having problems that occur, but only "sometimes", try this, see if situation improves:

```
<xct:Expander AnimationLength="0" ...>
```

That should remove the animation.

---

You can remove tests such as `if (_chart.PlotView == null && value.PlotView == null)` from your OnPropertyChanged-related code. That is, ALWAYS do the OnPropertyChanged.

REASON: in the future you might wish to generate a modified plot because data changed, and the tests you have would prevent UI from seeing the change.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I’ll try it out when I’m back on my computer (2 hours)

Comment: But it sounds like all I have to do is add those lines in my expanding method and make that one change?

Comment: Can I still keep the code that closes an expander when a new one is open?

Comment: @user979331 - Yes and Yes.

Comment: I just tried adding the code at the very top of my expander tab method, I eventually got the error again…I’ll post my new code and take a look at your repo. I had a few minutes to try it out but same error message eventually

Comment: Okay making a repo now

Comment: @user979331 - I've changed page to not use CollectionView. Result seems more responsive and fully reliable. See also other changes I suggest in this revised answer.

Comment: I made the repo, I put it in our private chat. I tried to apply your repo to my project and now nothing appears on the screen, just blank.

Comment: I got your code to work with my API. Thanks for your help, should be easy from here.